# How to perform uncommit operation in git?

Tags: git, reset

to perform uncommit operation on my code. I did:

`git reset --hard demo1.txt`

but it is showing :

`fatal: Cannot do hard reset with paths.`

I also tried this one:

`git reset --soft demo1.txt`

but showing the same result:

`fatal: Cannot do soft reset with paths.`

I am a bit new to git. so couldn't able to figure it out. what's wrong ?

Please help me resolve it.

Comment: Is your branch name `demo1.txt`?

Comment: @Justinas no this is my fileName .

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to uncommit a file, which won't work. If you want to uncommit your last commit (as seen at the top of `git log --stat`), do a

```
git reset HEAD~1
```

It will leave your changes uncommitted.  If you don't care about those changes, you can instead remove them with

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Comment: If you want to change only one file: perform `git reset HEAD~1` as here and then do a `git checkout demo1.txt` to checkout the uncomitted changes and then a new commit of all the other changed files will finish it off.